# Travis CI Build Failing

Tags: build-process, travis-ci

I am having an issue with Travis CI - the commits that I push all fail with the same error:

> 0.06s$ curl -sSL "http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key" | sudo -E apt-key add -
>   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
>   The command "curl -sSL "http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key" | sudo -E apt-key add -" failed and exited with 2 during .
>   Your build has been stopped.

I tried to rebuild a previous commit that built successfully and the same error occurs. Any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Travis is fetching the key over plain HTTP and trusting it unconditionally, nice

Comment: Does anyone know a good way to check when llvm apt repository is restored?

Comment: The llvm repo is back again

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key is returning 404 since about 2 days ago. And http://llvm.org/apt/ which is linked from their [homepage](http://llvm.org/) returns 404.

The topic in the `#llvm` channel on IRC mentions:

> APT repo temporary switched off. Check ML for the latest updates.

The [ML announcement](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-May/100303.html):

> TL;DR: APT repo switched off due to excessive load / traffic
>
> Recently we realized that APT repo generates almost 95% of I/O on
>   llvm.org and more than 40% of network bandwidth alone. During last 2
>   weeks the main services on llvm.org (svn, git, bugzilla) had serious
>   problems with overall connectivity.
>
> We decided to temporary switch APT repo off to see if this would help.
>   Stay tuned for updates.

Comment: Any proposed alt way to install new clang and llvm onto build bots?

Answer (score 2):

**Temp solution**

Since the llvm server still down I'm using the clang provided in the Ubuntu package.

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
      #- llvm-toolchain-precise-3.7
    packages:
      - libgnome-keyring-dev
      #- clang-3.7
      - clang
```

Full example: https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/blob/master/.travis.yml#L35

The only problem is that installs the version 3.4 or 3.5. Which looks be much slower than the latest one available on llvm package.

Answer (score 1):

The llvm server is still down. However, a **very** good idea from the people behind `rust` (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) is to solve this issue by using Docker.

See the .travis.yml file here: 
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/b1651fb4d2c0349ccca108b8d24210d688507936

You can find the travis build here:
https://travis-ci.org/rust-lang/rust/builds/134924068

I incorporated Docker into my builds with **excellent** results, but it took me a couple of days to do so. You can find my approach here: https://github.com/fuzzylite/fuzzylite/tree/master in files `/Dockerfile` and `/.travis.yml`

and the results here: https://travis-ci.org/fuzzylite/fuzzylite/builds/137058927

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6120#issuecomment-224072540) is an example how to currently solve this and use clang 3.7.

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty

env:
  global:
    - LLVM_VERSION=3.7.0
    - LLVM_ARCHIVE_PATH=$HOME/clang+llvm.tar.xz

before_install:
  - wget http://llvm.org/releases/$LLVM_VERSION/clang+llvm-$LLVM_VERSION-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04.tar.xz -O $LLVM_ARCHIVE_PATH
  - mkdir $HOME/clang+llvm
  - tar xf $LLVM_ARCHIVE_PATH -C $HOME/clang+llvm --strip-components 1
  - export PATH=$HOME/clang+llvm/bin:$PATH
```

I'm doing the same for clang 3.5/3.6/3.7/3.8 and it works.

I call `clang++` and not `clang++-3.7` or whatever - it is prepended to the PATH.